# Can we enhance the working or GetMetricData API for Amazon Connect Metrics OR any other API to use instead of GetMetricData?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am looking for an API like GetMetricData to pull/access the Metric Data (Historical & Real). This is because GetMetricData has only limited fields (options) to access but i'm looking to access rest of the fields as well like `Agent, Agent_First_Name, Agent_Last_Name, Agent_answer_rate, Agent_idle_time, Agent_on_contact_time, Online_time etc.`

but GetMetricData doesn't support these fields. So, can i enhance it's working to add these fields OR any other way to access these?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't an API call that will provide agent metrics. The only options I'm aware of are...

For real-time data, set up a Kinesis data stream for the Connect instance and process the events from that.

For historic data, schedule reports in Connect, then process the report csv files from the S3 bucket.